# Properties of glyceral with respect to cooking/baking?

Tags: food-chemistry

Out of curiosity I went looking for information or videos of people taste-testing monosaccharides and I came away surprised that I could find this for virtually every sugar except for the simplest (triose) monosaccharide: glyceral (glyceraldehyde). There is a lot about glycer**ol**, which may make searching for glycer**al** more difficult. In any case I was curious what it tastes like and if it could be used for baking.

Comment: Well, it's also sweet, but I don't think there's much point in using it.

Comment: Why not? Depending on how sweet it is it could be used as a sugar substitute, depending on its taste it could be useful (e.g. maltose), or it could change the structure/mouthfeel of baked goods...

Comment: Only hypothetically - why use something you'd need to synthesize vs stuff that occurs in nature in large amounts?

Comment: For fun! For high-end molecular gastronomy. For industrial baking...

Comment: One challenge is that the cyclization is much less favorable than for all the other aldoses, so the aldehyde is much more reactive with amines and such that are present in most foods. Maybe useful if you want to promote Maillard chemistry